# Strange behavior change in boost::bind / boost::function since 1.55

Tags: c++, boost

I was trying to compile [a project](https://github.com/kitware/burn-out) that was written against Boost 1.55 against newer Boost 1.63, and I am running into a really strange error related to `bind`/`function`. Here's the complete, simplified test case:

```
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <boost/function.hpp>

template < typename Arg1 = int, typename Arg2 = int, typename Arg3 = int >
class foo
{
public:
  using function_t = boost::function3< void, Arg1, Arg2, Arg3 >;

  void set_function( function_t f )
  {
    func_ = f;
  }

private:
  function_t func_;
};

class bar
{
public:
  bar()
  {
    foo_.set_function( boost::bind( &bar::func, this, _1, _2 ) );
  }

private:
  void func( int const&, int& ) {}

  foo< int, int > foo_;
};

int main()
{
  bar x;
  return 0;
}
```

...and some select snippets of the errors I'm getting:

```
/usr/include/boost/bind/bind.hpp:398:35: error: no match for call to ‘(boost::_mfi::mf2<void, bar, const int&, int&>) (bar*&, int, int)’
/usr/include/boost/bind/mem_fn_template.hpp:278:7: note: candidate: R boost::_mfi::mf2<R, T, A1, A2>::operator()(T*, A1, A2) const [with R = void; T = bar; A1 = const int&; A2 = int&] <near match>
/usr/include/boost/bind/mem_fn_template.hpp:278:7: note:   conversion of argument 3 would be ill-formed:
/usr/include/boost/bind/bind.hpp:398:35: error: cannot bind non-const lvalue reference of type ‘int&’ to an rvalue of type ‘int’
/usr/include/boost/bind/mem_fn_template.hpp:283:25: note: candidate: template<class U> R boost::_mfi::mf2<R, T, A1, A2>::operator()(U&, A1, A2) const [with U = U; R = void; T = bar; A1 = const int&; A2 = int&]
/usr/include/boost/bind/mem_fn_template.hpp:283:25: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
/usr/include/boost/bind/bind.hpp:398:35: note:   cannot convert ‘(& a)->boost::_bi::rrlist3<int, int, int>::operator[](boost::_bi::storage3<boost::_bi::value<bar*>, boost::arg<1>, boost::arg<2> >::a3_)’ (type ‘int’) to type ‘int&’
/usr/include/boost/bind/mem_fn_template.hpp:291:25: note: candidate: template<class U> R boost::_mfi::mf2<R, T, A1, A2>::operator()(const U&, A1, A2) const [with U = U; R = void; T = bar; A1 = const int&; A2 = int&]
/usr/include/boost/bind/mem_fn_template.hpp:291:25: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
/usr/include/boost/bind/bind.hpp:398:35: note:   cannot convert ‘(& a)->boost::_bi::rrlist3<int, int, int>::operator[](boost::_bi::storage3<boost::_bi::value<bar*>, boost::arg<1>, boost::arg<2> >::a3_)’ (type ‘int’) to type ‘int&’
/usr/include/boost/bind/mem_fn_template.hpp:299:7: note: candidate: R boost::_mfi::mf2<R, T, A1, A2>::operator()(T&, A1, A2) const [with R = void; T = bar; A1 = const int&; A2 = int&]
/usr/include/boost/bind/mem_fn_template.hpp:299:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘bar*’ to ‘bar&’
```

If I try on another machine that has Boost 1.55, it compiles just fine. (The project also compiled okay on the same machine when pointed to a build of Boost 1.55, so the problem does not seem to be the compiler.) So, apparently something has changed in Boost that is newly causing this to fail.

I didn't write this code, not am I intimately familiar with the guts of `boost::function` and `boost::bind`. If someone could explain to me why this is breaking with newer Boost, and either a) how to fix it, or b) why the above code is broken, it would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that `boost::function` has become stricter in matching the function signature (I think to more closely match the behavior of `std::function`). Your function is declared to be `boost::function3< void, Arg1, Arg2, Arg3 >`, however, the function you're binding to it takes `int const&` and `int&`.

There are a couple of ways to fix this. You could:

1. Change the instantion of `foo<int, int>` in `bar` to be `foo<int const&, int&>`.
2. Change the declaration of `function_t` to be `boost::function3<void, Arg1, Arg2 const&, Arg3&>`.
3. Change the signature of `bar::func` to accept its arguments by value.

Comment: Thanks. I'd say (3) is impossible because the troublesome parameters are output parameters, but digging deeper, AFAICT a) the actual code using this pattern can't possibly be producing a valid reference parameter with which to eventually invoke the stored function, and b) the actual type is anyway a reference container, and so will DTRT even passed by value/copy. So AFAICT, (3) is in fact the correct fix for the real code. (Note for the record: the `const&` arguments can still be adapted; only the reference parameter needs to change.)