# Boost 1.83 C2440 error in bind.hpp compile

Tags: boost, compiler-errors, casting

Here is one of several similar template models in bind.hpp, version 1.83:

```
  template<class R, class F, class A> R operator()(type<R>, F & f, A & a, long) 
  {
     return unwrapper<F>::unwrap(f, 0)(a[base_type::a1_]);
   }
```

It returns C2440 "Cannot convert void to boost::_bi::unspecified" in Visual Studio IDE 2022
I've tried various casts to no avail. Using std:c++20 (have tried others)
It's my only boost issue so far.

I tried various casts, such as static and dynamic, plain casts like (R), which is what the template wants. Nothing works.

Comment: Please share the minimal reproducer, and potentially relevant preprocessor defininitions. Re.: "have tried others" what happens when you use other language levels?

Comment: Have tried C++14 and 17 with the same results. Today, I worked around this issue by copying the bind folder from Boost 1_55 into my 1_83 source; I only had to make one small change to have it compile. Still, I'd like to get the 1_83 bind folder to build.

Comment: Please share the minimal reproducer. Some things DID change, but we cannot begin to see what impacts you. Without info all we can do is point at the release notes.

Comment: Or maybe just look for existing answers like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45549724/strange-behavior-change-in-boostbind-boostfunction-since-1-55

Comment: I can try going one by one through my cpp's using the 1_83 bind version and pinpoint the one that caused the error, as I did with the1_55 version, which had a clearer error message.

Comment: That would work! Happy to look at it when you find it

Comment: I finally gave up and used the old 1_55 bind folder in the 1_83 install. It was very easy to build now with a few updates to conform to 1_83, but I'll have to test the code to make sure it works. On debug/x64 Visual Studio.
A suggestion for boost developers: Please provide better info pointing back to the user code so that developers can debug their code.The errors are too obscure.

Comment: That's a good suggestion for compiler developers. However there are limitations due to language design. In the general case the template instantiations and overload need to be listed, which causes the famously unreadable error novels